# what does @synthesize someProp = _someProp do in a subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm kind of confused about something.  So I understand the memory management portion of doing something like

```
self.someProp = someObject;
```

But when you declare something as

```
@synthesize someProp = _someProp;
```

and you try to access _someProp in a subclass of the object, I get an error sayint that _someProp has not been declared.  But if I do self.someProp I dont' get the error.  Can someone explain what the differences are in these scenarios?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically creates the following code:

```
@implementation myClass
{
    @private
    id _someProp; // notice it's a private implementation property
}

-(id) someProp
{
    return _someProp;
}

-(void) setSomeProp:(id) prop
{
   [_someProp release];
   _someProp = [prop retain];
}

@end
```

The private implementation property means that it cannot be accessed outside of the class, and isn't a part of the interface, but a part of the implementation.

Comment: If in the interface, you have a declared ivar of _someProp, then this is available to subclasses right since it's now part of the interface? Thx

Comment: @JW Yes, assuming that you don't declare the iVar as private.

Answer (score 1):

`@synthesize someProp = _someProp;` creates getter and setter methods in your class. The methods are named `someProp` and `setSomeProp`. These method get and set a private variable named `_someProp` which is why that name is not available to your subclasses.